# Create new project on Android, Error: Studio Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'

Tags: android

After installing Android studio and creating a new project, I get the following error:

> Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'.
>
> Please ensure the host name is correct. If you are behind an HTTP
>   proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in Android Studio or
>   Gradle.
>
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try using this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369500/flutter-error-could-not-download-bcprov-jdk15on-jar-org-bouncycastlebcprov-jd

Answer (score 74):

I was also having the same problem.  I tried the following and it's working for me now:
Please try the following steps:

Go to..

*File* > *Settings* > *Appearance & Behavior* > *System Settings* >  *HTTP Proxy [Under IDE Settings]* **Enable** following option ***Auto-detect proxy settings***

On Mac it's under:

Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behaviour... etc

you can also use the test connection button and check with *google.com* to see if it works or not.

Comment: Had the problem, this solved it; but with the new Gradle update had to revert back to 'No Proxy'.

Answer (score 11):

I have same problem after update android studio to 1.5, and i fix it by update the gradle location,

1. Go to File->Setting->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle
2. Under Project level Setting find gradle directory

Hope this method works for you,

Comment: How do we do the same on Linux (e.g Ubuntu) please

Answer (score 8):

I tried above answers and they didn't help in my case.

I solved it with this link help:
http://vjscrazzy.blogspot.co.il/2016/02/failed-to-sync-gradle-project.html

> step 1) file>Setttings>appearance and behaviour> system setttings>HTTP
> proxy> set No Proxy
>
> step 2) build,execution and deployment> Build tools > gradle> now
> under project level settings > select local gradle distribution>
> gradle home = F:/Program Files/Android/Android
> Studio/gradle/gradle-2.4

After that, I did these changes(because it still wrote me some other errors)

Android Studio asked me:

1. Android Studio asked me to update my Gradle version (which he didn't before)
2. Enable - Tools> Android> Enable ADB integration.

Also, if your working in a team with repositories, it's important to check that the version of the Andorid Studio is the same.

Comment: when have installed `gradle` why must be download it agin! was very usefull.

Answer (score 3):

Go to setting option which is on upper strip of android studio and follow the below steps to solve the problem.

> setting > Appearance&behavior > HTTP and proxy > click on Auto detect Enable option.(The option with radio box)select this one...

Answer (score 0):

I also faced it and encorrected it like below successfully.

> File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Use local
> gradle distribution

Set the home path as : `C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-version`

You may need to upgrade your gradle version.