# Installing the previous deleted libraries and tools of API 23

Tags: android

I had downloaded the API 23 and all its supporting tools and libraries but once I got an error due to API 23 and deleted all along the directory from the SDK and storage as well which I found from this following.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183122#makechanges

Now I want to reinstalling all these but its not displaying in SDK while the latest API (API 24) is displayed.

I am trying to reinstall for past 3-4 days but no progress.

---

**EDIT**

I got the option to re-install the api 23 but it shows the error as mentioned in the comment.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What exactly do you need from SDK 23 that can't be built with SDK 24?

Comment: There's nothing in SDK 23 which's not in 24. But after updating my SDK 2.1.2 to 2.1.3, its showing an error in building a gradle file as similar in this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664820/errorunknown-host-services-gradle-org-you-may-need-to-adjust-the-proxy-setting

Comment: But the answers available there doesn't helped me

Comment: which folders you have deleted from SDK folder

Comment: Proxy settings have nothing to do with downgrading the SDK and don't affect the build process once you get the SDK. If you have proxy problems, your network may be blocking you from communicating with the Android dependency servers

Comment: From Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7
all the folders after 22.2.1 and even from maven-metadata.xml in the same directory as mentioned in the above URL post #8

Comment: It sometimes even give the error that Gradle build failed

Comment: Just before i have installed api 24, after that i did like this, sdk->buildtools->removed api 24, platforms->removed api 24, removed all the api 24 stuff, now it will building the  projects with api 23 supporting tools.

Comment: Yeah but my SDK manager neither shows SDK 23 nor it shows the msg of SDK 24 installed completely. Whenever I starts SDK manager it shows the msg **partially installed**

Comment: Install 23, settings->androidsdk->android 6.0. and uncheck android7.0

Comment: also delete android-24 from sdk->sources, if have

Comment: how to do, cause its not available there in SDK manager

Comment: will SDK 2.1.3 the latest stable version work without api 23 & 24 both

Comment: you are using android studio right?

Comment: @user5594218 yeah in win 8.1

Comment: file->settings->androidsdk-> sdk platform tab, in that all the android versions names available. you just install android android 6.0

Comment: none the tab are working only except the default tab. the button above these tabs near edit opens another window and asks for downloading

Comment: the default tab shows the API 22 and older version but after API 22 it shows API 24 only

Comment: Any idea friends for error    "Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle." Under headline Failed to sync Gradle project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your immediate response. I solved the error after upgrading the gradle version and its plugins.

Thanks again