# Android studio is not showing Activity_main.xml

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, gradle, unknown-host

Android studio is not showing `Activity_main.xml`. Compiling produces the following output:

> Gradle project sync failed,
> Unknown host 'repo.maven.apache.org
> you may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:Unknown host services.gradle.org. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664820/errorunknown-host-services-gradle-org-you-may-need-to-adjust-the-proxy-setting)

Comment: Can you please share your build.gradle here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you're connected to the internet
2. Disable gradle offline mode
3. Check your firewall and proxy settings