# Gradle message in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting this message:

> Error: Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.

[image]

Comment: This may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678137/create-new-project-on-android-error-studio-unknown-host-services-gradle-org

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new project on Android, Error: Studio Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678137/create-new-project-on-android-error-studio-unknown-host-services-gradle-org)