# open existing project from newer or older android studio version unknown host 'service.gradle.org'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

i have install android studio 2.2.2 on my Desktop and it works well with new created project 
but the problem when i open a project created in an older or newer version of 2.2.2
i got error message unknown host 'service.gradle.org' as attached image
[please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VnOI.jpg)

i tried to set up gradle home path for downloaded project but doesn't fix the problem

also i tried this solution but it doesn't work too

> File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy
>   [Under IDE Settings] Enable following option Auto-detect proxy
>   settings

please any help or suggestions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new project on Android, Error: Studio Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678137/create-new-project-on-android-error-studio-unknown-host-services-gradle-org)

Comment: This is a network problem. Check proxy and firewall settings.

Comment: hello thank you for your reply Matt Clark and Henry but i don't have a problem with creating new project the problem if i open an existing project created in an older or newer version of android studio

Comment: _Possible_. Check the answers. Just because questions are slightly different, does not mean the answers won't solve your problem.

Comment: @MattClark i tried most of solutions in the article but they don't work maybe i will try install latest version of gradle as mentioned in  one of solutions