# How I can sync gradle using downloaded archive in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I install android 2.3.3, but i cant sync gradle because I dont have internet connection. But i have downloaded gradle archive, how I can sync gradle using this archive?

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this inside Android Studio, I'm using version 2.3.3  -

> Preferences -> Gradle -> Global Gradle Settings -> Offline work

But you have to build it online once to be able to do this later.

Check this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158034/how-to-setup-android-studio-to-work-completely-offline) for more information.

Comment: Where i can find preferences menu? I can run local web server for simulate gradle website

Comment: The Preference is for Mac which is basically Settings in Linux/Windows, if you are using Linux/Windows just try this shortcut - Ctrl + Shift + A and type Gradle, the settings that opens up, from there you can enable Gradle offline work.

Comment: Thanks. How android studio check connection with services.gradle.org? Im host local web server, in browser all normal, but android studio say that connection refused

Comment: You can check this in order to fix this - [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678137/create-new-project-on-android-error-studio-unknown-host-services-gradle-org)