# Gradle building refresh failed in android studio

Tags: android

It shows `error: unknown host service.gradle.org`. i adjust settings in gradle even. I tried uninstalling & installing it with various versions. but it gives the same error. In the xml file in design it shows nothing although I coded.

Comment: Please at least *exactly* present the error; better yet, enable everyone interested to reproduce it. (Try using a spelling checker.)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Create new project on Android, Error: Studio Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678137/create-new-project-on-android-error-studio-unknown-host-services-gradle-org)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new project on Android, Error: Studio Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678137/create-new-project-on-android-error-studio-unknown-host-services-gradle-org)