# Android Studio 3.1 run build Gateway Time-out

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-studio-3.1

I updated Android Studio from 3.0.1 to 3.1, and updated Gradle from 4.1 to 4.6

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

And I get this error

```
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar'. 
Received status code 504 from server: Gateway Time-out
```

I tired [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19864829/9391388), but still having the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510176/android-studio-gradle-sync-failed-could-not-head-received-status-code-5