# How to create gradle project without internet use "Offline Components" in Android studio 3.4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

How to apply "Offline Components" in my project which i know it can make project gradle offline without internet connection, i found it from official android studio website.

I already follow the instruction from the page but still not know how to apply it in my project, here is the [instruction](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#offline)

and this picture is what i did so far

[image: pict one], [image: pict two], [image: pict three], [image: pict four], [image: pict five]

so what i miss? Or what i do

Comment: Check if this reference is helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158034/how-to-setup-android-studio-to-work-completely-offline

Comment: For error 'Unknown host services.org.gradle' , try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678137/create-new-project-on-android-error-studio-unknown-host-services-gradle-org